# I can't see the output from Serial.print. Why?

Tags: c++, printing, monitor, baud-rate

I have been trying to setup a program analyzing stock-prices for quite some time. I didn't manage to get any output however, so I decided to do some testing with simpler programs... MUCH simple programs. Right now I can't even manage to get "Hello World" to work, using platformio. If someone could tell my why I would appreciate it a lot.

main.cpp:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Hello World!");
}
```

platformio.ini:

```
[env:esp32-poe-iso]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32-poe-iso
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
```

I have tried changing the baud-rate and setting different COM-ports as the monitor-port. I don't manage to get any good result / any result at all however, and I am running out of ideas to why

Comment: Add a language-specific tag. Is it `C`?

Comment: Did that (Edited)